# ckeditor 4.5.1 drag and drop image into editor fails

Tags: drag-and-drop, ckeditor4.x

Before CKEditor 4.5.1 it was possible to drag and drop images into the editor and save them as base64, at least in FireFox.  This no longer seems to be possible.  Dragging an image into the editor gives no result at all, whereas in other browsers the image is loaded into a new tab, which seems to suggest that  in FireFox the process is entirely blocked.

Comment: can you explicitly say what your question is?

Comment: Before 5.4.1, dragging an image into the editor area embedded the image in the editor as a base64 string, so that the image displayed in the editor.  (This worked only in Firefox.)  On saving, I converted the string to a standard image file. So, I would like to know if I am missing something.  For instance, is there a configuration option which enables this functionality?

Comment: Here is a demo: https://youtu.be/gRWw4QjbUVA

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can drag an image into the paste tool and save it as a base64 string.  See: https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin:ckgedit:drag_and_drop